# How do I rename DFS shares?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

Is there an easy way to rename the DFS shares, some of the folders have changed function and we would like to update this with their names?

Comment: DFS isn't a single product. Are you talking about folders that are in a DFS namespace or that are replicated with DFSR or both? If it's in a namespace, do you want to rename just the namespace, or also the targets?

Comment: I have a namespace, it is the folders under the namespace that i want to change the names of. I was told by my colleague that it was a very difficult and long drawn out process and that I shouldn't bother! Although they didn't elaborate more than that.

Comment: I would guess that he referred to the fact that you would need to change all references to the Dfs links as well which can be tiresome. If you do not care about references, the technical part is simple - [just rename](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736868(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: I would need to make sure that the end users would still be able to access them . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not changing the namespace shares themselves, but rather subfolders like your comment suggests there's no black magic. You just change them.

Comment: If I change them, I need to make sure that all the links, programs and user access don't change. Are these updated automatically?

Comment: If the paths are hardcoded into applications and configurations, then no. It won't update automatically. DFS isn't magic. The ACLs on the folders will stay the same, though.